# controlling number of http hit per second in PHP

Tags: php

can anyone share best way to control per second http hit in php. I have to restrict http hit to 20 per second through PHP code. 
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How are you suppose to do that? The PHP code will not run without me hitting your server.

Comment: That's the job of your web server configuration, not php.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the response to just 20 hits per second and send blank responses to others you can consider using some caching technologies like memcached or use redis to maintain a count and both technologies can be used with expiry so you can use them to limit the rate. Ideally I would do it on the server (apache/nginx) itself.

Comment: you misunderstand my question , I have to call another http url from php page but I have to put some logic so that I can not hit more than 20 hits per seconds. e.g I have 1000 records , i need to send it one by one by calling http url. i can just iterate and hit http url but in this case there may be chances I hit more than 20 in a second.

Comment: yeah so in a similar way, you can keep a record of how many calls have you already made in memcached or redis

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by restricting number of hits on particular port of your php server by iptables settings